# How can I get the list slice using a list of indexes in Python?

Tags: python, slice

In Perl I can easily select multiple array elements using a list of indexes, e.g.

```
my @array = 1..11;
my @indexes = (0,3,10);
print "@array[ @indexes ]"; # 1 4 11
```

What's the canonical way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 7):

use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
array = range(1, 12)
indices = itemgetter(0, 3, 10)
print indices(array)
# (1, 4, 11)
```

Then present that tuple however you want..., eg:

```
print ' '.join(map(str, indices(array)))
# 1 4 11
```

Comment: wow!! Thanks. From where you get to know all these techniques:)

Comment: @rajpy It's worth taking the time (although not all in one sitting) to read through the [library reference](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/index.html) to see what is there.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> array = range(1, 12)
>>> indexes = [0, 3, 10]
>>> [array[i] for i in indexes]
[1, 4, 11]
>>>
>>> list(map(array.__getitem__, indexes))
[1, 4, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> indexes = (0,3,10)
>>> x = np.arange(1,12)
>>> x [np.array(indexes)]
array([ 1,  4, 11])
```